# Locating all NDRs without Sent message Exchange Online

Tags: exchange-2016, exchangeonline

In a Hybrid Exchange 2016/EOL environment we have our webserver configured to send mail directly out via our on-premise Exchange server. We had an issue, now resolved, that was blocking the server from sending some, but not all messages. The From address on these messages was set to info@domain.com, which is a real email address, so while we don't have a copy of the sent message, we do have NDRs for the messages that failed. We can't just blanket re-send everything as there are an unknown number of emails that were successfully sent.

All told, there are around 12,000 messages that need to be identified and referenced to the orders they are in regards to. There are ~15 different subjects which we need to sort through.

If possible, I'd rather not have to go through Outlook to do isolate the failures, but NDRs don't seem to show up when I try to run an eDiscovery or Content search on the mailbox.

Once I have the messages exported, I can go through them relatively easily and automate the correlation process, but I can't figure out how to isolate, or export just the failure messages, without having to drop into Outlook and do it manually. The manual process on a subset of these messages has yielded different results for each person that's done it, and is incredibly tedious, so I'd like to avoid it.

Is there a PowerShell method to isolate all the NDRs, or something that I'm missing from within the 365 portal?

Is there a way that this can be done so that I can export the NDRs including the subject line to different folders for easier matching with the orders they represent?

Comment: The only way i can think of is to run "Search-Mailbox" command with specify query to found out all NDR messages: Get-Mailbox | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'Diagnostic information for administrators' -TargetMailbox "Discovery Search Mailbox" -TargetFolder "AllMailboxes" -LogLevel Full